# Why does clipboard stop working, whenever I open a remote desktop session

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, clipboard

With my recently fresh-installed Win 8 system I am running into a strange problem:
Whenever I start a remote desktop connection, the clipboard locally and remote stops working. As soon as I close the session, it works again.

This is what I investigated so far:

- Killing and restarting rdpclip doesn't change anything
- It only occurs AFTER starting the session - just opening the RDP session leaves everything working intact
- Shortcuts (ctrl + c) as well as right click actions are affected
- Only the clipboard is affected. Other shortcuts, like ctrl+w,  work on both systems even while the connection is up

Any idea on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I restore copy/paste functionality for my remote desktop connection?](http://superuser.com/questions/399917/how-can-i-restore-copy-paste-functionality-for-my-remote-desktop-connection)

Comment: sadly not, no. All answers refer to the rdpclip problem..

Comment: I have the same problem with Windows 10. I don't even have rdclip.exe.