# File copy and paste over RDP stopped working

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop, copy-paste, file-transfer

I use Remote Desktop from a Window 8.1 Pro 64 bit PC to a remote Windows XP Pro SP3.

Recently I noticed copy&paste of files does not work in either direction.

Copy&paste of text and images (from/to MS Paint) works fine (in both directions).

The trick with restarting rdpclip.exe does not help (note: rdpclip.exe is only on XP, I think it does not exist on Windows since Vista - *wrong: it still does*). See: [Why does copying over RDP sometimes not work?](https://superuser.com/questions/552108/why-does-copying-over-rdp-sometimes-not-work) and [Can't copy and paste in Remote Desktop Connection session](https://superuser.com/questions/95609/cant-copy-and-paste-in-remote-desktop-connection-session).

Today (19 mar 2015) it happened on Windows 7 Pro SP1 64 bit connecting to Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2. Text works, files not. Both directions.

Comment: On my work PC (Win7ProSP1 64 bit) connecting to a WinXPProSP3, copy-paste of files works in both directions.

Comment: rdpclip.exe still exists in Windows Server 2012 R2